# While using redux, 'payload' property is undefined when the getter method is being invoked

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm unable to access my property defined as a getter.

I've console.logged all segments feeding that property, so i think the getter definition is wrong.

```
export const messageThreadChecker = (_uid) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    chatRef.child(_uid).on('value', snap => {
        !snap.exists() && dispatch(finishThreadCheck(false));
        dispatch(finishThreadCheck(!snap.val().isActivated ? {
            status: 'pending'
        } : {
            status: 'active',
            get payload() {
                chatRef.child(snap.val()._tid + '/messages/').orderByKey().limitToLast(1).once('value', (_message) => {
                    var _lastRef = _.values(_message.val())[0]._id;
                    userRef.child(snap.val().provider.id)
                        .once('value').then((snapshot) => {
                            return {
                                correspondent: {
                                    name: snapshot.val().name,
                                    avatar: snapshot.val().avatar
                                },
                                threadId: snapshot.val()._tid,
                                lastRef: _lastRef,
                            }
                        })
                })
            }
        }))
    })
};
```

Upon attempting to access the payload property, I'm getting the following:

```
{status:'active',payload:undefined}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a getter doesn't return anything than its property value is undefined.

Your payload getter function doesn't return anything because it has no return statement. Maybe you wanted this?

```
export const messageThreadChecker = (_uid) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    chatRef.child(_uid).on('value', snap => {
        !snap.exists() && dispatch(finishThreadCheck(false));
        dispatch(finishThreadCheck(!snap.val().isActivated ? {
            status: 'pending'
        } : {
            status: 'active',
            get payload() {
                return chatRef.child(snap.val()._tid + '/messages/').orderByKey().limitToLast(1).once('value', (_message) => {
                    var _lastRef = _.values(_message.val())[0]._id;
                    userRef.child(snap.val().provider.id)
                        .once('value').then((snapshot) => {
                            return {
                                correspondent: {
                                    name: snapshot.val().name,
                                    avatar: snapshot.val().avatar
                                },
                                threadId: snapshot.val()._tid,
                                lastRef: _lastRef,
                            }
                        })
                })
            }
        }))
    })
};
```

Comment: This actually returns a promise. Firebase functions return promises. But it feels like we’re moving in the right direction